# How do you call computer graphics created using lines and fills defined by mathematical equations?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

How do you call computer graphics created using lines and fills defined by mathematical equations?

Comment: Lacking some relevant context the question, as it is, seems broad?

Comment: Hello mckenzie, welcome to GD.SE. I'm sorry to be blunt, but your question looks an awful lot like a homework assignment. A Q&A site is not a good place to post those. If you have any questions about the site, have a look the [help]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: try this]

https://www.coursehero.com/flashcards/611877/CS5-Ai-Chapter-1/

> Vector Graphics
>
> resolution independent graphics created with lines curves and fills
> but consist of anchor points and line segments (paths) created for mathematical equations based on geometric principles

Answer (score 3):

While its true that the question is looking for the answer vector graphics*. I feel that this sort of definition is not really constructive. Often used but still a bit bad definition.

First of, the image is not usually constructed out of mathematical equations generally. But splines, usually béziers. And even the lines in mainstream applications are just straight bézier segments.

A considerably better definition would call "mathematical functions": "continuous curves". Even that definition leaves something to be desired as all non-discrete, on demand rendered imaging systems can be considered vector graphics.

However, most people do not consider something vector graphics, unless they can open it in some standard format (PS, EPS, PDF, AI, DXF...). Even so as these can contain bitmap graphics they do not consider the formats themselves vector only the curves inside the formats. Likewise people do not consider 3D applications vector applications even though they clearly are, just because they can not access the data easily.

* this is what happens in schools, we teach people to figure out what teacher expects not what is